# Query mongo to detect value changes in time series

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, time-series, aggregation-framework

Im wondering if the following is possible in MongoDB.

I have collection of documents that represent changes in some value in time:

```
{
  "day" : ISODate("2018-12-31T23:00:00.000Z"),
  "value": [some integer value]
}
```

There are no 'holes' in the data, I have entries for all days within some period.

Is it possible to query this collection to get only documents that has different value than previous one (when sorting by day asc)? For example, having following documents:

```
{ day: ISODate("2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"), value: 10 }
{ day: ISODate("2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z"), value: 10 }
{ day: ISODate("2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z"), value: 15 }
{ day: ISODate("2019-04-04T00:00:00.000Z"), value: 15 }
{ day: ISODate("2019-04-05T00:00:00.000Z"), value: 15 }
{ day: ISODate("2019-04-06T00:00:00.000Z"), value: 10 }
```

I want to retrieve documents for `2018-04-01`, `2018-04-03` and `2018-04-06` and only those since others don't have a change of value.

Comment: is there anyway to append the last record also to the above result? for example, if the change happened at 2018-04-06 and that particular value continued, then the last record is not retrieved. I need to get the last record as well. any help is most appricated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get pairs of consecutive docs to detect the gap. For that you can push all documents into single array, and [zip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip) it with itself shifted 1 element from the head:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $sort: { day: 1 } },
    { $group: { _id: null, docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
    { $project: {
        pair: { $zip: {
            inputs:[ { $concatArrays: [ [false], "$docs" ] }, "$docs" ]            
        } }
    } },
    { $unwind: "$pair" },
    { $project: {
        prev: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$pair", 0 ] },
        next: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$pair", 1 ] }
    } },
    { $match: {
         $expr: { $ne: ["$prev.value", "$next.value"] } 
    } },
    { $replaceRoot:{ newRoot: "$next" } }
])
```

The rest is trivial - you unwind the array back to documents, compare the pairs, filter out the equal ones, and [replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot) from what's left.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. If you don't mind, I have one follow up question: Is it possible to add grouping by some other field to this data (for example userId)? I thought I will manage to do this by myself, but Im having some troubles.

Comment: But of course. If I get the question right you only need to replace `$group: {_id: null` with `$group: {_id: "$userId"`. If it is not what you are after, please ask a proper question with formal data snippets and expected results.

Answer (score 2):

Starting in `Mongo 5`, it's a perfect use case for the new [`$setWindowFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/)  aggregation operator:

```
// { day: ISODate("2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"), value: 10 } <=
// { day: ISODate("2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z"), value: 10 }
// { day: ISODate("2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z"), value: 15 } <=
// { day: ISODate("2019-04-04T00:00:00.000Z"), value: 15 }
// { day: ISODate("2019-04-05T00:00:00.000Z"), value: 15 }
// { day: ISODate("2019-04-06T00:00:00.000Z"), value: 10 } <=
db.collection.aggregate([

  { $setWindowFields: {
    sortBy: { day: 1 },
    output: { pair: { $push: "$value", window: { documents: [-1, "current"] } } }
  }},
  // { day: ISODate("2019-04-01T00:00:00Z"), value: 10, pair: [ 10 ] }
  // { day: ISODate("2019-04-02T00:00:00Z"), value: 10, pair: [ 10, 10 ] }
  // { day: ISODate("2019-04-03T00:00:00Z"), value: 15, pair: [ 10, 15 ] }
  // { day: ISODate("2019-04-04T00:00:00Z"), value: 15, pair: [ 15, 15 ] }
  // { day: ISODate("2019-04-05T00:00:00Z"), value: 15, pair: [ 15, 15 ] }
  // { day: ISODate("2019-04-06T00:00:00Z"), value: 10, pair: [ 15, 10 ] }

  { $match: { $expr: { $or: [
    { $eq: [ { $size: "$pair" }, 1 ] }, // first doc doesn't have a previous doc
    { $ne: [ { $first: "$pair" }, { $last: "$pair" } ] }
  ]}}},

  { $unset: ["pair"] }
])
// { day: ISODate("2019-04-01T00:00:00Z"), value: 10 }
// { day: ISODate("2019-04-03T00:00:00Z"), value: 15 }
// { day: ISODate("2019-04-06T00:00:00Z"), value: 10 }
```

This:

- starts with a [`$setWindowFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/) aggregation stage which adds a `pair` field representing the current document's value and the previous document's value (`output: { pair: { ... }}`):

  - `$setWindowFields` provides for a given document a view of other documents (a `window`)

    - which in our case is the `"current"` document and the previous one `"-1"`: `window: { documents: [-1, "current"] }`.
    - such that we build within this window an array of values: `$push: "$value"`
    - and note that we've made sure to sort documents by day: `sortBy: { day: 1 }`.
- and then:

  - filters in the first document (which is remarquable by its array having only one element): `{ $eq: [ { $size: "$pair" }, 1 ] }`
  - and filters out the following documents if their `pair` has the same values: `{ $ne: [ { $first: "$pair" }, { $last: "$pair" } ] }`